# Select % of pixel that have a specific value in R

Tags: raster, r, raster-calculator

I have a the following raster layer

```
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 3865, 6899, 26664635  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 14.83, 14.83  (x, y)
extent      : 361363.5, 463675.7, 5760647, 5817965  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : 0, 1  (min, max)
```

Out of the pixels that have value `1`, I want to create a new raster that contains only 20 %.

I have tried the solution explianed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42161011/how-to-select-in-a-raster-pixels-with-specific-values but it is not completlety working in my case and I am looking for something more direct.

Is there any suggestion?

-- EDIT --

Having this similar raster layer:

```
> LC
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 1523, 1251, 1905273  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 14.83, 14.83  (x, y)
extent      : 435676.6, 454229, 5778354, 5800940  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : 0, 1  (min, max)
attributes  :
 ID value
  1     0
  2     1
```

When using the proposed code to create a `dataframe` with pixels having value 1

```
k<- which(LC[]==1)
validationDF<-data.frame(S1[k])
```

The output I get also includes those having differnet values. Here an example of the output:

```
3               0.54203808           0.24895041           0.22670831           0.46078694           0.50426632    NA
74               0.50227493           0.31457043           0.54777414           0.32805267           0.22595555    NA
75               0.35207680           0.54237461           0.43180075           0.33425951           0.38486433    NA
76               0.36328074           0.41732568           0.70713311           0.55753678           0.55029380    NA
77               0.41078874           0.31826615           0.53114951           0.57591325           0.64157540    NA
78               0.45285624           0.22833233           0.42914906           0.38943154           0.37679926    NA
79               0.39223304           0.34883267           0.43133700           0.53802007           0.24752679    NA
80               0.28511491           0.83619344           0.32504967           0.58656722           0.12048869    NA
81               0.32361615           0.83749610           0.49244761           0.55320078           0.28306779     2
82               0.46567097           0.71770340           0.73712200           0.69843239           0.37452736     2
83               0.74498045           0.87335765           0.84909189           0.84107888           0.60185462     2
84               0.88498110           0.90481257           0.88580418           0.83265042           0.82502586     2
85               0.80765188           0.81705832           0.78906369           0.64642227           0.86415219     2
86               0.51198280           0.34016779           0.64171618           0.45680562           0.70922333     2
87               0.36744031           0.48365906           0.67687130           0.37062010           0.66719669     1
88               0.43470848           0.56459582           0.72314465           0.55038470           0.66051489     2
89               0.53563386           0.69634366           0.73726457           0.57873970           0.57167530     1
90               0.64553213           0.67632288           0.68176281           0.51696473           0.46562076
```

Comment: You want to change 20% of the "1" pixels to have the value "0"?

Comment: No, just create a new raster where only 20% of the pixels (selected randomly) that have value 1 in the original raster are contained. The remaining 80% should be no data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a reproducible example:

```
> set.seed(123)
> r = raster(matrix(sample(c(0,1,NA),25*25,TRUE),25,25))
> plot(r)
```

[image]

How many ones, zeroes, and NA are there?

```
> table(r[],useNA="always")

   0    1 <NA> 
 211  204  210
```

Which cells are the ones?

```
> ones = which(r[]==1)
> head(ones)
[1]  8 21 32 52 59 62
```

Sample 0.8 of them randomly to become NA. Sorting isn't strictly necessarym but shows how its a subset of the ones above:

```
> missing = sort(sample(ones, length(ones)*0.8))
> head(missing)
[1]  8 21 52 62 68 99
> r[missing]=NA
```

and that leaves us with:

```
> plot(r)
```

[image]

which has more NAs and fewer ones in it:

```
> table(r[],useNA="always")

   0    1 <NA> 
 211   41  373
```

Comment: Thanks, from your proposal I see that the output is not created as a `raster`. My intention is to used this selection (20%) as input (training) for an image classification

Comment: `r` *is* a raster - I've shown you `r[]` which gets the values from `r`, and tabulated them.

Comment: Edit shows a reproducible example, and plots the before and after.

Comment: I had an alternative which is to create random points over 20% of pixels and then use that as reference for the new raster but I prefer your solution

Comment: I have edited the question to add a similar case